# How to communicate vector from a class component to another component in React Native?

Tags: react-native, class, components, communication, react-props

I am trying to communicate the letterVec from the ClassComponent class to the TextComponent class so that I can display it there. Below is the code for the ClassComponent class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList} from 'react-native';

class ClassComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      letterVec: ['B'],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title={'Add A'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState(
              (this.state.letterVec = [...this.state.letterVec, 'A']),
            );
          }}
        />
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          data={this.state.letterVec}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return <Text>{item}</Text>;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default ClassComponent;
```

Here is the TextComponent code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import ClassComponent from './ClassComponent';

const TextComponent = () => {
  const classC = new ClassComponent();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Text Component, {classC.state.letterVec}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default TextComponent;
```

I have been able to make the TextComponent show letterVec, but it isn't updated in the TextComponent screen when I updated it on the ClassComponent screen. How can I show the most updated version?

Comment: This is not the correct way to communicate data on React. Please refer to [React useContext hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext). You need to use a context state instead so you can access `letterVec` through all your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
This isn't the right way to get values.
Try Passing letterVec as prop to TextComponent 
Like <TextComponent letterVec={this.state.letterVec}/>

and then use it like this
const TextComponent = (props) => {
return (
     <View>
       <Text>Text Component, {props.letterVec}</Text>
     </View>);
}
```